# filtering rows in a datatable or dataframe based a column that happens to be a list

Tags: r, list, filter, subset

I would like to filter this data table, but the column I want to filter by is a list.

```
#example data
time= c(1, 2, 3, 4)
conditions = list('rain', 'rain', c('rain', 'sleet'), 'rain')
data = data.table(date, conditions)
print(data)

   time conditions
1:    1       rain
2:    2       rain
3:    3 rain,sleet
4:    4       rain
```

The normal commands don't seem to work:

```
# Data.Table
data[conditions == c('rain', 'sleet')] # Gives error
# dplyr
filter(data,conditions == c('rain', 'sleet')) # Doesn't return desired result
```

Please advise.

Comment: So you only want to keep the rows where conditions are a list or only where they are exactly c("rain", "sleet")? Does order matter? Would you also want c("sleet", "rain")?

Comment: Either one would be fine. In my real code they will generally be in a consistent order anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `identical`:

```
data[sapply(conditions, identical, c('rain', 'sleet')), ]
```

or with `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  filter(map_lgl(conditions, identical, c('rain', 'sleet')))
```

**Output:**

```
   date conditions
1:    3 rain,sleet
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `purrr` package and pass the `identical` function.

```
library(dplyr)    
library(purrr)

data %>%
  filter(map_lgl(conditions, ~identical(c('rain','sleet'), .))) 

> time  conditions
>    3  rain, sleet
```